# Not able to import @Inject annotation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, kmm

I have implemented Hilt dependencies in my project, but when I need the @Inject annotation for my constructor, it's not working. basically when I tried to import it manually i found out, the inject folder inside javax is empty. So the structure is like javax.inject. And after that I get nothing as the inject folder is empty. I have tried rebuilding and cleaning he project. I also tried by Invalidating caches but nothing seems to work. How can I make this work ?

Dependencies List

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":shared"))

    implementation(AndroidX.appCompat)

    implementation(Compose.runtime)
    implementation(Compose.runtimeLiveData)
    implementation(Compose.ui)
    implementation(Compose.material)
    implementation(Compose.uiTooling)
    implementation(Compose.foundation)
    implementation(Compose.compiler)
    implementation(Compose.constraintLayout)
    implementation(Compose.activity)
    implementation(Compose.navigation)

    implementation(Google.material)

    implementation(Hilt.hiltAndroid)
    implementation(Hilt.hiltNavigation)
    kapt(Hilt.hiltCompiler)

    implementation(Kotlinx.datetime)

    debugImplementation(SquareUp.leakCanary)
}
```

Hilt version - 2.37

Comment: Could you please add your dependency list here?

Comment: Yeah, i have updated the question with dependencies used

Comment: @user477174 have found any solution I am getting the same error! Android Studio 4.2.2

Comment: having the same error here, have you found a solution?

Comment: I was able to "fix" it by downloading android bumblebee version

Answer (score 1):

All your dependency is right, it's just an android studio bug!

I am having the same problem using Android Studio 4.2.2, I solved using the beta version of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)

Comment: Thanks, this helped get me around my issue. Hopefully that bug gets fixed soon on stable!

Comment: @AndrewSteinmetz it's solved now! which version of kotlin you are using?

Comment: Still having this issue on Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
 downloaded Android studio Bumblebee and it worked

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened with my Android Studio installation, but the only way I could fix this was with Jetbrains toolbox to uninstall and reinstall arctic fox and managed to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Solved uninstall Artic Fox version, and download  Bumblebee version

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the plugins in the gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

Comment: I do have all these plugins in my gradle file

Answer (score 0):

If your javax folder is empty, you need to remove the javax cache and let the Gradle download it again.

1. right-click on javax library and choose Library Properties
   [image]
2. in the dialog, go to the address and remove that folder to let the Gradle download the library again.
   [image]
3. sync the Gradle. It will download the jar and the folder will not be empty anymore

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're annotating with the @Inject (uppercase I) and not @inject with a lowercase i.